# Create wave file from a string

Tags: c#, string, wave

Solved, thanks. It's base64 and this works.

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String(columns[6]);
```

Thanks again.

I got a TSV file, and inside this file there're audio stored as original string and related wave info. One wave and its info per line. What I need to do is to read each line, get the audio, and save them as separated wave files.
One sample of wave string is like this:

> UklGRpgiAABXQVZFZm10ICwAAACUAgEAgD4AAPAKAAA4AAAAGgABAA8AKACOAgEAgD4AANAHAAAoAAAAAgBAAWRhdGFYIgAAQMQKQPQTQTQSQTQSQTQUQYNBVBNBJBJBJBNBJBRBRKFEE0EkE0FEFEE0FEFUFQAAAAAAAAAAAADACOmRY92lbj7+7kGhMFC3V9I3qMyjX2G8vAclkKFxUlD26mS+1qCRMV4OuVCxXf/IxrFBj///9sAG0iRqqUOIIRKT/4vqBtdWJF6pI/mWgPFx6JlUIFUPm6gofbyf93hJ6NCbgja88uTflydp///

And I tried to read this line and use:

```
byte[] waveContext = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(columns[6]);
File.WriteAllBytes(waveFullPath, waveContext);
```

But the output file contains just the same string.
Does anybody got ideas on how to handle this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Looks like base64. Is it?

Comment: You need to know how the bytes were converted to a string in the first place. You can't just convert arbitrary bytes to a string and get something as 'readable' as that, so there must be a conversion of some sort (e.g. Base64). If so you need to reverse that conversion.

Comment: Yep, it's Base64 encoded WAV file

Comment: Please remove all but the first 4 lines form your example. It makes no sense to waste this space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a base 64 encoded string.

```
 byte[] waveBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
```

Don't know how to build up a wave file. This may help you: [MSDN: Creating wav files in C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/29ae621a-175a-4410-bf91-b052f58bd9ee/creating-wav-files-in-c?forum=csharplanguage). (10secs lookup with Google.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "audio stored as original string".

Audio data is **binary data** usually (these days) two channels à 16Bits interleaved
prepended by a short (binary) header which contains number of channels and sampling rate.

Read about "RIFF WAV" file format.